# How to write bootloader for Oracle virtual box HDD format (VDI files)

Tags: linux, assembly, virtualbox

I am trying to create a bootloader which can run on Oracle virtual box using GNU assembler(gas). After searching Internet I found that there is no information about this. I am trying to write it for VDI HDD format of Oracle virtual box. Can someone tell me how to achieve it. I have already tested a bootloader using floppy drive feature of Oracle virtual box and it is running fine.

Comment: Why not code your bootloader as normal then use `VBoxManage convertfromraw` to convert the image to vdi?

Comment: Thanks Jester, I will try it. Will you please provide me steps to create it.

Comment: Does thisanswer help any? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43566542/virtualbox-no-bootable-medium-found/43566982#43566982

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Thanks Michael Petch. Information mentioned in link is what I was looking for. 